# What is this "was.drupal" directory?

Tags: drupal, directory, backup

I'm working on a Drupal installation followed till now by a person I cannot contact anymore. Inside my Drupal directory there's a "was.drupal" directory. Does someone know what it could be? I'm pretty sure it is generated by some kinf od drupal tool, but I don't know what.

Comment: What's in it? This is not generated by core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that anything like was.drupal exist in the directory structure of drupal.

You can refer:

- [Directory Structure](https://drupal.org/node/1938494)
- [Drupal 7 Folder Structure & important files](http://codingcyber.com/drupal-7-folder-structure-important-files-1307/)
- [Drupal: How to structure your modules directory](http://befused.com/drupal/module-directory-structure)

Comment: You're right. Abandoned the idea of an automatic generation, i've examined the content and now i guess that "was drupal" explained all. I think it was a manual backup of some previuous version of the drupal installation. Thank you for the references! Now i can delete all and forget about it.